# windows server Active Directory users data into Windows Phone 7?

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, active-directory

How do I connect to windows server active directory using Windows Phone 7 without using a web service/ WCF. Microsoft didn't provide "System.DirectorySerice" namespace in Windows Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not an available part of the platform for WP7 developers. A web service and/or WCF is the only option in this first release.